# Как добавить в exe файл дополнительную информацию?

Tags: php, javascript, c#, сервер, exe

есть билд программы в нем есть место для записи доп.информации (до 200 символов)
как можно с помощью сервера или php (вообщем через web) при отдаче файла юзеру (при скачке) записывать доп.информацию в exe файл и отдавать его юзеру??
Изменять данные внутри файла и НЕ переподписывать его, сохраняя при этом корректную цифровую подпись.

Comment: Что означает "место для доп информации"? это поле из ресурсов versions или из ресурсов xml? Может это экспортная переменная?  Вообщем эта информация должна быть привязана к MZ или PE заголовку - тогда её можно вычислить, и быть может менять.

Comment: @nick_n_a совершенно не обязательно она должна быть к привязана к чему-то. Соответствие между VA и смещением в файле однозначное.

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, соответствие между VA и смещением в файле задаётся двойным словом с смещением в 03Сh.

Comment: @nick_n_a И как же это поле по смещению 0x1C  называется? В MZ-заголовке его нет. В PE это SizeOfCode, а в заголовке секции - некие LineNumbers

Comment: это поле задаёт смещение PE заголовка относительно МZ. Оно попадается разное.

Comment: @nick_n_a VA в смещение - таблица секций, скажем сразу.

Comment: Цифровая подпись на то и подпись, чтобы при любом изменении файла она становилась невалидной.

Answer (score 1):

Никак*. Цифровая подпись содержит вычисленный хэш от бинарного представления исполняемого файла. Поэтому, изменение любого бита в исполняемой файле делает подпись недействительной.

---

*** Конечно, можно подобрать коллизию, если алгоритм позволяет, но, я полагаю, овчинка выделки не стоит.